# How to update a table using SQL in a PHP code?

Tags: php, sql

If the row for a specific user relevant to a specific product in the table called "user_star_rate" is null, I want to insert the data to the table and otherwise I want to update the table. But the update function is not working.

```
$jsqla7 = mysql_query("select * from user_star_rate where product_id='$product_id' and email='$visit_email'") or die(mysql_error());
$jfeta7 = mysql_fetch_assoc($jsqla7);

if($jfeta7 != null) {
    $rate = "UPDATE user_star_rate SET rate_value='$rate_value' WHERE product_id='$product_id' and email='$visit_email'" ;
} else {
    $rate = "INSERT INTO user_star_rate (email, product_id, rate_value) VALUES ('$visit_email','$product_id','$rate_value')" ;
}
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated. You should use mysqli_* or PDO. You also should use prepared statements to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Look into `REPLACE INTO`

Comment: try `mysql_num_rows($result) != 0` instead of `$jfeta7 != null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$jfeta7 = mysql_fetch_assoc($jsqla7);
if($jfeta7 != null) {
```

to

```
$jfeta7 = mysql_num_rows($jsqla7);
if($jfeta7 > 0) {
```

Note: mysql_ functions are deprecated and do not use it. They will be removed in the upcoming versions of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($jsqla7 )==0)
{

//INSERT
}
else
{
//UPDATE
}
```